# Adding a Query to a Form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am a fairly new user to Access. I'm creating a form that reqires information from 2 different queries. Prepare yourselves for probably the easiest question asked here before!

I'm wondering how I can get the field values from my 2nd query into my Form?

Is there an open new query button or something basic I'm missing? If my question isn't clear, I'll gladly clear it up if theres any confusion.

Comment: Perhaps an easier question would be; How can I run an update query to add 3 additional fields to my current Table? I've done this before, I'm just drawing a blank.

Comment: Are you wanting to do a Join of two queries and show/modify the results on one form; or are you wanting to show the results from one query on the form, and then have sub-form with the results of the other query (showing only the related records)?